# Why are almost all utility classes in spring declared as abstract rather than final?

Tags: java, spring, utility

[spring-framework/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util at main · spring-projects/spring-framework · GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/main/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util)

eg: [spring-framework/ClassUtils.java at main · spring-projects/spring-framework · GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.java#L57)

```java
/**
 * Miscellaneous {@code java.lang.Class} utility methods.
 * Mainly for internal use within the framework.
 *
 * @author Juergen Hoeller
 * @author Keith Donald
 * @author Rob Harrop
 * @author Sam Brannen
 * @since 1.1
 * @see TypeUtils
 * @see ReflectionUtils
 */
public abstract class ClassUtils {
    // omitted
}
```

eg: [spring-framework/CollectionUtils.java at main · spring-projects/spring-framework · GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/CollectionUtils.java#L44)

```java
/**
 * Miscellaneous collection utility methods.
 * Mainly for internal use within the framework.
 *
 * @author Juergen Hoeller
 * @author Rob Harrop
 * @author Arjen Poutsma
 * @since 1.1.3
 */
public abstract class CollectionUtils {
    // omitted
}
```

It is mentioned in Item 4 of "Effective Java": Enforce non-instantiability with a private constructor.

> Attempting to enforce noninstantiability by making a class abstract does not work. The class can be subclassed and the subclass instantiated. Furthermore, it misleads the user into thinking the class was designed for inheritance (Item 17).

From [Item 4: Enforce noninstantiability with a private constructor | Creating and Destroying Java Objects | InformIT](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=4)

Comment: Maybe so they can be extended with additional utilities.

Comment: @shmosel I checked the source code, almost none was inherited.

Comment: I mean by users of the library.